# Sending a byte array (type `ay`) over D-Bus using GDBus

Tags: c, dbus, gdbus

I am trying to a byte array over D-Bus using the GDBus bindings. Can you please let me know how I can achive that. I tried googling but didnt help.

Byte array contains a image file so cannot be converted to charbytearray

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6220704/1744123) has some good ideas in the answers including for passing large amounts of data by [writing the data to a file and passing the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6220781/1744123), or [using a named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12622541/1744123).  Writing to a file and passing the file name might be the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 11):

I did some tests using an XML where I used the type `ay`. This works well with the QT binding (generated with `qdbusxml2cpp`) where it translates into `QByteArray` however it seems that it doesn't work with the glib binding (generated with `gdbus-codegen`) where it translates in `gchar *` and it seems you lose what's after `\0` - because somehow it's handled as a string. However you will find that:

> This automatic mapping can be turned off by using the annotation org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant - if used then a `GVariant` is always exchanged instead of the corresponding native C type. This annotation may be convenient to use when using bytestrings (type-string `ay`) for data that could have embedded NUL bytes.

Which means according to https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-codegen.html that you could handle it as `GVariant`. I tested this by adding the tag for annotation `org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant` `<annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant" value="true"/>` on each arg and it works.

Comment: I think this one is the correct answer to the question. And i would rather use ''--annotate'' option along with gdbus-codegen than adding it to the xml file
@cyrax thanks ..!

Comment: Can you please post a sample xml file with the annotation? this not working for me.

Comment: Just in case some case someone else is puzzled by how to create a `"ay"` GVariant from `char *`:
`gchar *data = ...;
GBytes *bytes = g_bytes_new(data, data_size);
g_variant_new_from_bytes(G_VARIANT_TYPE_BYTESTRING, bytes, TRUE);`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, instead of using type "ay", you can use "a(y)". The glib binding would translate "a(y)" to GVariant*.

And then you can use "GVariant" handling to deal with the parameter.

e.g. the xml file

```
<method name="parsePacket">
  <arg direction="in" name="message" type="a(y)">
    <doc>
      <line>type: const Uint8 *</line>
    </doc>
  </arg>
</method>
```

Generated method:

```
gboolean (*handle_parse_packet) (
IDbusObject *object, GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation, GVariant *arg_message);

gboolean idbusobject_call_parse_packet_sync (
   IDbusObject *proxy,
   GVariant *arg_message,
   GCancellable *cancellable,
  GError **error);
```

You can extract and insert data using "GVariant" method.

Insert data at client side:

```
void parsePacket (unsigned char* arg_message, guint16 arg_length)
{
    GVariantBuilder *builder;
    GVariant *value;

    builder = g_variant_builder_new (G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(y)"));
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_length; i++)
    {
        g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(y)", arg_message[i]);
    }
    value = g_variant_new ("a(y)", builder);
    g_variant_builder_unref (builder);

    idbusobject_call_parse_packet_sync(proxy,
        value,
        NULL,
        NULL);
}
```

Extract data at server side:

```
gboolean handleParsePacket (
    IDbusObject *object,
    GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation,
    GVariant *arg_message)
{
    unsigned char byteArray[2048];
    int actualLength = 0;

    GVariantIter *iter;
    guchar str;

    g_variant_get (arg_message, "a(y)", &iter);
    while (g_variant_iter_loop (iter, "(y)", &str))
    {
        byteArray[actualLength++] = str;
    }
    g_variant_iter_free (iter);

    idbusobject_complete_parse_packet( object, invocation);

    return (TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Using type `a(y)` instead of `ay` is a hacky workaround; you should be using the `org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant` annotation instead, as per cyrax’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the client side, you could do it easier by calling the g_variant_new_from_data() method:

```
GVariant* convertByteArrayToVariant(unsigned char* arg_message, guint16 arg_length)
{
    return g_variant_new_from_data(
        G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(y)"),
        arg_message,
        arg_length,
        TRUE,
        NULL,
        NULL);
}
```

Or, if you have a populated a GByteArray*, you could do it like this:

```
GVariant* convertByteArrayToVariant(GByteArray* array)
{
    return g_variant_new_from_data(
        G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(y)"),
        array->data,
        array->len,
        TRUE,
        NULL,
        NULL);
}
```