# How to annotate an xml file with org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant using gdbus-codegen

Tags: c++, dbus, bluez

I am attempting to annotate an xml file so that dbus-codegen generates a method that uses GVariant * instead of a native type like gchar.

Here is the xml code I am working with.

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1">
    <method name="WriteValue">

        <arg name="value" type="ay" direction="in"/>

    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

I have read the following stackoverflow post:

[Sending a byte array (type `ay`) over D-Bus using GDBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937588/sending-a-byte-array-type-ay-over-d-bus-using-gdbus)

After reading that post I have tried the following:

1)Edit the xml file to include annotations

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1">
    <method name="WriteValue">
      <annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant" value="true">
        <arg name="value" type="ay" direction="in"/>
      </annotation>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

then do:

```
gdbus-codegen --interface-prefix org.bluez --c-generate-object-manager --generate-c-code generated-code org.bluez.xml
```

This did not generate what I wanted.

2)Use the --annotate switch on gdbus-codegen:

```
gdbus-codegen --annotate "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1.WriteValue()" org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant true --interface-prefix org.bluez --c-generate-object-manager --generate-c-code generated-code org.bluez.xml
```

This did not generate what I wanted.

The only way I have been successful is to change the "ay" in the following code to "a(y):

```
    <annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant" value="true">
    <arg name="value" type="a(y)" direction="in"/>
    </annotation>'
```

However this causes other problems.

So how do I get a WriteValue method with the following declaration:

```
    gboolean gatt_characteristic1_call_write_value_sync
    (GattCharacteristic1 *proxy,
    GVariant *arg_value,
    GCancellable *cancellable,
    GError **error)
```

instead of:

```
    gboolean gatt_characteristic1_call_write_value_sync (
    GattCharacteristic1 *proxy,
    const gchar *arg_value,
    GCancellable *cancellable,
    GError **error)
```

Can some please tell me what I am doing wrong.

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As [documented in the D-Bus specification’s section on the introspection data format](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#introspection-format), you need to use `<annotation>` as a self-closing element, rather than surrounding the `<arg>` element.

So you want:

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1">
    <method name="WriteValue">
      <arg name="value" type="ay" direction="in">
        <annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.ForceGVariant" value="true"/>
      </arg>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

You can also see examples of this [in the GLib source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/1273fa39938ac3e7031c3fc99ef2e966aac565ac/gio/tests/test-codegen.xml#L176).