# Saving a GdkPixbuf from a DBus client/server result in different files

Tags: dbus, vala, gdkpixbuf

I have a DBus service that creates a Variant type for a Pixbuf file that when saved on either side gives two different files, despite the data being the same. The image saved from the server side is correct, the one on the client side shows the top 1/3 correct, middle 1/3 shifted horizontally by 1/3 of the width and the colors are wonky, and the bottom 1/3 shifted by 2/3 the width and has different wonky colors.

The Variant on the server side is created thusly

```
var image_var = new Variant ("(iiibi^ay)",
                             width,
                             height,
                             stride,
                             has_alpha,
                             bits_per_sample,
                             data);
```

and unpacked by the client using

```
Variant data_var = null;
image.get ("(iiibi@ay)",
           &width,
           &height,
           &stride,
           &has_alpha,
           &bits_per_sample,
           &data_var);
```

On both sides I print things about the pixbuf, including a checksum. The server side gives

```
Width:         1024
Height:        768
Stride:        3072
Bits/Sample:   8
Has Alpha:     false
Data Length:   786432
Data Checksum: e1facf66095e46d7ca3338b6438c1939
```

and the client

```
Width:         1024
Height:        768
Stride:        3072
Bits/Sample:   8
Has Alpha:     false
Data Length:   786432
Data Checksum: e1facf66095e46d7ca3338b6438c1939
```

Everything is definitely the same, the call to save the image for both is

```
pixbuf.save (filename, "jpeg", "quality", "100", null);
```

This has been tested and wonkiness has been verified on three different computers. I will provide a complete example, likely tomorrow. I just wanted to put this out there first without it in case someone has come across this before.

Comment: The key part will be how you are loading the received data on the client side vs the original image on the server side. NB: Since you're just transmitting things like the width, height, etc across the bus, they are all irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending large data blobs like images in D-Bus messages is not what D-Bus is designed for — it’s intended for control messages, not large data messages. You’ll get bad performance, and will likely hit the D-Bus message size limits for larger images. See [Passing a large data structure over dbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220704/passing-a-large-data-structure-over-dbus) for an example of that.

Instead, you should send a handle to the image data. D-Bus provides functionality for this in the form of the [file descriptor type](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#basic-types) (type string `h`), which allows you to pass a file descriptor for the image data from one process to another. The file descriptor could be an unnamed pipe, or could be an open read-only file, for example.

Comment: I kind of figured this was how it should work, but I saw an example that did it directly using a Variant and thought I might get away with it. Upon further inspection that was for tiny cover art images for media notifications so not as much data being transmitted.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. You should be looking at hard limits of a few hundred bytes of image data for that approach to make sense.