# How to run paste <(zcat f1.gz) <(zcat f2.gz) using python's subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, paste, zcat

I am trying to run `paste <(zcat f1.gz) <(zcat f2.gz)` using subprocess.
Here's what I have done so far:

```
ps1 = subprocess.Popen(('zcat', 'f1.gz'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.Popen(('zcat', 'f2.gz'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps3 = subprocess.Popen('paste', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But I am not sure how to provide ps3 with both ps1.stdout and ps2.stdout as inputs. I would appreciate it if you guys can help me with this and let me know if I am on the right track.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers when they solve your problem (checkmark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is largely inspired by this post
[allowing multiple inputs to python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589839/allowing-multiple-inputs-to-python-subprocess)
where the problem is slightly different.

Basically one solution is to use a *fifo* : subprocesses write in the
fifo while a thread consumes data written by subprocesses.

```py
import subprocess
import os
import threading

#  create our fifo for data exchange between processes
os.mkfifo('my-fifo')

#  create a reader thread that consumes data from our fifo
def read_from_fifo():
    with open('my-fifo', 'rb') as fd:
        subprocess.Popen('paste', stdin=fd)
t = threading.Thread(target=read_from_fifo) 
t.start()

#  write commands output to our fifo
with open('my-fifo', 'wb') as fifo:
    for cmd in [('zcat', 'f1.gz'), ('zcat', 'f2.gz')]:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        fifo.write(p.stdout.read())

t.join()  # wait that our thread has consumed all data
os.unlink('my-fifo')
```