# Creating temporary named fifo in *nix system

Tags: linux, unix, fifo

I have some tasks requiring massive temporary named pipes to deal with.

Originally, I just simply think that generate random numbers, then append it as `<number>.fifo` be the name of named pipe.

However, I found this post: [Create a temporary FIFO (named pipe) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430446/create-a-temporary-fifo-named-pipe-in-python)

It seems there is something I don't know that may cause some security issue there.

So my question here is that, what's the best way to generate a named pipe?

Notice that even though I am referencing a Python related post, I don't really mean to ask only in Python.

UPDATE:

Since I want to use a named pipe to connect unrelated processes, my plan is having process A call process B first via shell, and capture stdout to acquire the name of pipe, then both know what to open.

Here I am just worrying about whether leaking the name of pipe will become an issue. Before I never thought of it, until I read that Python post.

Comment: What security issues are you thinking of? Where would you store the name of the fifos? Why can't you use plain anonymous pipes?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch because it requires IPC between processes have no relationship. the security problem here seems to be malicious attacker? i don't quite understand actually. i worry because i found that post.

Comment: But you could use random names, and the issue is how do you share (or where do you store) these names. You should edit your question to explain more.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i am confused after reading that post. it seems randomization may be error-prone too. i updated my question.

Comment: BTW, I am skeptical about the massive usage of `mkfifo`. Do you need a dozen of them or a million of them? (at some given moment, I guess that the kernel is limiting the number of fifos to several hundred thousands).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i changed my mind a little bit, so it won't need too many now. it has chance to go hundreds at most, which should be ok.

Answer (score 6):

If you have to use named FIFOs and need to ensure that overlap/overwriting cannot occur, your best bet is probably to use some combination of `mktemp` and `mkfifo`.

Although `mktemp` itself cannot create FIFOs, it can be used to create unique temporary directories, which you can then put your FIFOs into.

The [GNU mktemp documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html) has an example of this.

Comment: The trouble with using `mktemp()` is that some systems warn about its use at link time, and that is a nuisance if you're aiming for no warnings in your build.  I got here looking for a solution to that problem; this wouldn't meet my requirements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Perhaps `mkstemp()`, then?

Comment: I concluded that creating a function `int mkptemp(char *pattern, mode_t mode)` would likely be best, doing roughly the same job as `mkdtemp()` does — creating a 'pipe' (FIFO) with a random name, which would be stored in the `pattern` argument. I've not implemented it, but could easily modify an implementation of `mkstemp()` to create a FIFO instead of a file. The `mkfifo()` system call won't create a FIFO at the end of a broken symlink — like the `mkdir()` system call, it fails if the name exists in the file system. I'd use p for 'pipe' rather than f for 'fifo' because f suggests 'file' too.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could create some name containing well random letters. You could read from `/dev/random` (or `/dev/urandom`, read [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)) some random bytes to e.g. seed a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (e.g. [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) seeded by `srandom`), and/or mix the PID and time, etc.

And since named [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) are files, you should use the permission system (and/or [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)) on them. In particular, you might create a command Linux user to run all your processes and restrict the FIFOs to be only owner-readable, etc.

Of course, and in all cases, you need to "store" or "transmit" securely these FIFO names.

If you start your programs in some `bash` script, you might consider making your fifo names using [mktemp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) as:

```
fifoname=$(mktemp -u -t yourprog_XXXXXX).fifo-$RANDOM-$$
mkfifo -m 0600 $fifoname
```

(perhaps in some loop). I guess it would be secure enough if the script is running in a dedicated user (and then pass the `$fifoname` in some pipe or file, not as a program argument)

The recent [renameat2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/renameat2.2.html) syscall might be helpful (atomicity of `RENAME_EXCHANGE`).

BTW, you might want some SElinux. Remember that opened file descriptors -and that includes your fifos- are available as symlinks in [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) !

<sup>PS. it all depends upon how paranoid are you. A well sysadmined Linux system can be quite secure...</sup>